# Plesk servers and Drupal Apache module requirements

Tags: 7

Recently I have leased a shared server where I manage everything via Plesk and do the nitty gritty configurations via ssh.

Plesk comes default with almost every Apache module enabled, and my processes are over 100 megs each, which is way too high. Here is a list of them:

```
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
```

I have learned a lot by researching the community about what Drupal needs on sites like 2bits.

However my question is, can I just turn all these off and enable the bare minimum that Drupal needs to run as mod_php?  By turning any of these off, would I actually affect how Plesk operates (which we need it to work fine in house for those doing general administration for the domains this server handles).

If nothing here would affect how Plesk works, then I ll be happy to just turn them all off, except for the hand full of modules drupal needs.  And, by the way, I of course have conflicting information about what drupal 'needs' to run leanly. Which of the modules in this list would you suggest I keep to run drupal?

thoughts?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that Apache's modules are causing the high memory usage ? Does your Drupal instance has a lot of modules enabled ? Because 2bits blog especially refer to the "open buffet syndrome" of Drupal where sites run hundreds of modules and cause high memory consumption.

Comment: I have about 50 core and contrib modules enabled. Read the open buffet article, which was really helpful. But read more on there as well that suggested unnecessary Apache modles, as well as unnecessary server applications, would also use resources unnecessarily. So this is the first place I would like to start in tuning this as lean as I can get it. However, for now, I am stuck with Plesk and its overhead.

Comment: Indeed 50 Drupal modules isn't much. Have you tried to custom a separate server install without plesk to see how much memory can you save by removing apache modules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, Drupal will need many of those.

In my experience, Plesk is **very** picky about server configuration and may not run properly once you start mucking with the Apache and/or PHP settings.

Personally, I would not run a Drupal site on a Plesk managed machine, but that's me.  I start out with the barebones CentOS and go from there.  With Apache, I don't need to turn on/off any additional standard modules, though I will usually also install [the module](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Apache-Version2#Download) that allows HTTP range requests for H.264.